# How to read a UTF-8 text file in VBScript

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, vbscript

I have a text file saved as UTF-8 and when I try to read the file it gives me weird characters and not the correct characters (it contains Chinese characters). How can I make it give me the correct Chinese characters?

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, strTextFile, strData, strLine, arrLines, aniTextFile, aniData, aniLines, aniLine, objTextFile, fso, inputFileList, listFile, fname
Dim iim1, iret, iret2, iret3, i
Const ForReading   = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTextFile = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ArtistCG\folder.txt"
strData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTextFile,ForReading).ReadAll
arrLines = Split(strData,vbCrLf)

aniTextFile = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ArtistCG\folder-list.txt"
aniData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(aniTextFile,ForReading).ReadAll
aniLines = Split(aniData,vbCrLf)

For i = 0 To UBound(arrLines)
  strData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(arrLines(i),ForReading).ReadAll
  WScript.Echo strData

  Set listFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(aniLines(i),ForReading)
  Do While Not listFile.AtEndOfStream
    fName = listFile.ReadLine
    WScript.Echo fName
  Loop
  listFile.Close
Next
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198708.aspx):

> The FSO can read only ASCII text files. You cannot use the FSO to read
>   Unicode files or to read binary file formats such as Microsoft Word or
>   Microsoft Excel.

Since you got weird characters, I guess that's somewhat incorrect and the file was read in some 8-bit windows code page because if it really could read only ASCII, you would have seen `????`

Anyway, if you can use [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676526(v=vs.85).aspx), you can do this:

```
Dim objStream, strData

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ArtistCG\folder.txt")

strData = objStream.ReadText()

objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
```

Comment: It's true that `FSO` can't read UTF-8, but actually you can open the file as ASCII with `FSO` and [read the content char by char in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6087783/2165759), then convert that sequence of chars to the string [considering each char as a byte of UTF-8 encoded file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). It's just an academic interest; `ADODB.Stream` definitely is the most efficient.

Comment: It's not true that "FSO can read only ASCII text files" - FileSystemObject can read UTF-16 files, but not UTF-8 see @Ekkehard.Horner comment on the answer by user2171987

Comment: objStream.ReadText() doesn work

Answer (score -2):

I get my data. I just write "ReadText" twice :)

```
strData = objStream.ReadText(1) // return first char
strData = strData & objStream.ReadText(-1) // returm full text
```