# VBS File Read: Change CR FF to CR LF

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, fso

I have txt and csv files to be read per line. A line ends with `CR-LF`.
But in some files, there is `CR` and no `LF`; instead, next physical line starts with `FF`. UFT 12 reads them together, as if it was one line.
I read files using fso:

```
Dim FileRead : Set FileRead = fso.OpenTextFile(file1)
Dim file2Read : Set file2Read = fso.OpenTextFile(file2)

FileStrR = FileRead.ReadLine
File2StrR = FileRead.ReadLine
```

I need to compare each line of these file with another text file:

```
if FileStrR = File2Str Then...
```

I tried to separate the `FileStrR` as array:

```
FileStrA = REPLACE(FileStrR, ChrW(12),"**")
strarray = split(FileStrA,"**")
For h = 0 to UBound(strarray)
    FileStr = strarray(h)
    if FileStr = File2Str Then...
...
```

But here I stuck to read next line from the File2 to compare with whatever comes after `FF`.

**UPDATE**
Tried to SkipLine:

```
Do Until fileRead.AtEndOfStream
ln=ln+1
FileStrA = REPLACE(FileStrR, ChrW(12),"**")
strarray = split(FileStrA,"**")
For h = 0 to UBound(strarray)
    FileStr = strarray(h)
    For s=1 to (ln+h)-1
       File2Read.SkipLine
    Next

print ln&"-"&ln+h&"-"&h

    File2Str = File2Read.ReadLine
    if FileStr1 = File2Str Then...
print "F1: "&FileStr
print "F2: "&File2str
    Next
    Loop
```

In this peace of code, the line `print ln&"-"&ln+h&"-"&h`prints correct numbers (ln should be the number of the line currently read). But the string print (`print "F1: "&FileStr & VBNewLine & "F2: "&File2str`)gives the following:

> F1: 2|8122|TX|...
>
> F2: 4|8123|FG|...

It seems even if `ln+h` is 'ln' while 'h' is 0, but the `fso` skips one more line.

Comment: I open it in Notepad++, also printed what UFT reads. For those lines (it is like 1 in 65 lines), it is as follows:
`...`
`Line 64 Text CR-LF`
`Line 65 Text CR`
`FF Text CR-LF`
`Line 67 Text CR-LF`
`...`

Comment: It says UTF-8.
Tried to convert to ANSI; it added a `LF` after `CR`.
Problem is, ideally I cannot and have no access to redefine encoding or save file as new file with other encoding that it has originally ((

Comment: Something is not right with your file encoding, that's for sure. What does a hex editor show? Can you include that in your question for both files? Also show the code that reads the file (the definition of `FileRead`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23620307/603855) to learn that you can't use

1. the FileSystemObject to read/write UTF-8
2. .ReadLine if the EOLs are messed up (not CrLf or Lf)

If your files are ANSI/UTF-16 and not to big, you can use

1. .ReadAll to slurp the 'bad' file
2. Replace CrFF with CrLf
3. Split on CrLf to get an array of lines
4. these lines to compare to the .ReadLines from the 'good' file

If .ReadAll is not possible, you must write your own version of .ReadLine that scans for CrLf or CrFF and returns the data before those EOLs.

Comment: Files are UTF-8, and their size vary from couple KB to couple dozens MB...((( 
By the way, FSO reads any file with not messed up EOLs really well, dependless of the size )

Comment: @Salek if you are using FSO to read a UTF-8 file, that is your problem. While it may “appear” to read it right what you end up with is a encoding mismatch which will come back to bite you. You need to stop assuming you know best and heed the advice being given.

Comment: @Salek - My answers has the link (chain) to the docs that unequivocally state that FSO is **NOT** for UFT-8. So you are like the man jumping from a high building who still grins when passing the 5th floor - even worse, you invite other people to jump after you.

Comment: Cannot change anything in original file, but with ReadAll replaced FF to LF and saved as new file with ANSI. Now, ReadLine works ))

Comment: @Salek fine, it works you go do it your way. What you are failing to understand is due to the way UTF-8 is organised some common character will map fine, but they are still UTF-8 encoded. So by reading them as ASCII you will end up with mismatched encoded characters, it is that simple. But hey, you know better then us right.

Comment: @Lankymart, I got that point) But so far found no option to read files by other method but FSO readline - thats lack of my knowledge, need more research. Unfortunately, at the moment have no time for that due to deadline. For now, this is solving the current problem.
By the way, thnx to comments here, learned more about encodings and file reading. Will return to this issue and try to find a better solution.
Really appreciate your help))

Comment: @Salek use `ADODB.Stream` with `Charset = “UTF-8”`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13855268/692942