# Read from txt and clean \x00

Tags: vbscript

I have a .txt with this format:

[image]

I can remove the NUL characters in Notepad++ like this:

[image: Solution]

So I read about it, and I found the solution to replace the regular expresion "\x00" for " " ... but I need to create a VBScript. I found examples like this one:

```
sPath = "C:\Users\AL\T_1538_89945.txt"
sContent = ReadTextFile(sPath, 0) ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
sContent = Replace(sContent, "\x00", " ")
WriteTextFile sContent, sPath, 0

Function ReadTextFile(sPath, lFormat)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, lFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Sub WriteTextFile(sContent, sPath, lFormat)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 2, True, lFormat)
        .Write sContent
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work, can someone adapt the code so it can run it from that location cleaning those regular expressions?

Comment: Can you debug and check what is the value of sContent after reading the file? I suspect your file is UTF encoded and hence FSO isn't dealing with it correctly.

Comment: You are using Notepad++ so you should be able to tell the encoding just by looking at the bottom right corner

Comment: @PankajJaju Ohhh ok - UTF-8 is the encoding

Comment: There are many similar questions here on SO. Check this out --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851473/read-utf-8-text-file-in-vbscript

Comment: @PankajJaju So i have to use ADO to read the file, but that will allow me to replace those 'NUL' ??

Comment: Ahh yes missed that bit. Actually now that I thought about it I think you just need to make one simple change. Answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line `sContent = Replace(sContent, "\x00", " ")`

To this `sContent = Replace(sContent, ChrW(0), " ")`

You were trying to replace a string "\x00" and not the actual NULL char. I used [ChrW()](https://ss64.com/vb/chrw.html) to replace that particular char with space. Null is represented by character 0 and hence now we are not replacing a string but NULL char.