# Removing ï»¿ from Email Signature in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I made an excel macro to send multiple emails at once based off user data. I changed the .body to .htmlbody to allow the use of bolding, etc.; however, when I call the email signature, it's placing ï»¿ before the actual signature in the email. I found out that it's due to UTF-BOM encoding, however, in this instance, I'm not able to simply update the encoding of the file. I need the script to actually open the file with the updated (UTF-8) encoding, but not altering the file at all. Here's my code so far. I left most of the code out since I believe the only update will be done on the "GetBoiler" function.

```
Dim SigString As String
Dim Signature As String


SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
    "\Microsoft\Signatures\Default English - Main.htm"

If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
    Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
Else
    Signature = ""
End If

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* 

See "[ask]" as well as **how to create a [mcve]** (yours isn't).  Also, here's a "perfect question" [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user.

Comment: @ashleedawg I added all the information needed... I just need to know how to open a file with a different encoding....

Comment: See the links provided (specifically [mcve]) to see what should/shouldn't be included in an example, so that others can reproduce your problem. If you "just need to know how to open a file with a different encoding", that should be the focus of the question and only *relevant code* to that should be included.

Comment: @ashleedawg Your answers are not helpful. I said in my question exactly what is occurring, with the code that is producing the issue. I explained the exact issue and what I believe would need to be fixed, but added the code in the event that a simple change is needed. How is that incomplete in any way? If you can't provide a solution, then why are you commenting?

Comment: At a start, what you are doing with `Signature` would be helpful to know. The idea behind a [mcve] is that people can easily recreate the problem. It's also a good exercise for you to go through, as it can often narrow down a problem and save you having to post a question at all!

Comment: For starters, you have told us the contents of your signature and two you left us in the dark about what `getBoiler` is/where you found it. There’s no need to be rude.

Comment: @ashleedawg is among the site's [top answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/topusers) in the VBA tag, I wouldn't dismiss their answers as "unhelpful" that fast; they're trying to help you shape up your question so that it's useful to everyone that comes across a similar problem, which is exactly what this site is about (SO isn't "please help *me* debug *my* code" - take the [tour] to see for yourself), and ensures your questions are well-received so that you enjoy your SO experience. Please [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), it makes a better Internet for everyone.

Comment: Also, the BOM should not appear in the middle of text, only before it. It is not part of the text. It is metadata. Therefore, it shouldn't even appear in a `String`. If your method of converting bytes to `String` copies it in, get rid of it in the same function.

Answer (score 1):

### [FSO](http://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object) can't read [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

> [From the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198708.aspx):
>
> > **The FSO can read only ASCII text files.** You cannot use the FSO to read
> >     Unicode files or to read binary file formats such as Microsoft Word or
> >     Microsoft Excel.
>
> Since you got weird characters, I guess that's somewhat incorrect and the file was read in some 8-bit windows code page because if it really could read only ASCII, you would have seen `????`
>
> Anyway, if you can use [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676526(v=vs.85).aspx), you can do this:
>
> ```
> Dim objStream, strData
>
> Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
>
> objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
> objStream.Open
> objStream.LoadFromFile("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ArtistCG\folder.txt")
>
> strData = objStream.ReadText()
>
> objStream.Close
> Set objStream = Nothing
> ```
>
> ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13855268/8112776))

---

### Outlook Signatures

- Ron de Bruin : [**Working with Outlook signatures**](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm)
- Stack Overflow : [**How to add default signature in Outlook**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8994116/8112776)