# WScript.Shell read output in UTF8

Tags: excel, vba, character-encoding

I am trying to read the Output from the WScript.Shells Exec return value.
Some lines contain Chinese/German/Cyrillic characters
Like this:

> Glas f**ü**r Rahmen

The problem is, that I receive the "wrong" characters in my VBA Script.

Can I alter the charset of my `StdOut`? The Developer of the executable, which I start via the WScript.Shell, ensured, that the output is UTF8.
If I start the executable in the CMD I can see the correct characters.

```
Private oShell As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
End Sub

Public Function StartExeAndGetOutput(executable As String, arguments As String) As String
    Dim returnValue As Object

    Set returnValue = oShell.Exec(executable & " " & arguments)

    Dim oOutput As Object
    Set oOutput = returnValue.StdOut

    Dim s As String
    Dim sLine As String
    While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
        sLine = oOutput.ReadLine
        If sLine <> "" Then s = s & sLine & vbCrLf
    Wend

    StartExeAndGetOutput = s
End Function
```

Comment: Not sure what this executable does but would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851473/read-utf-8-text-file-in-vbscript) not be a viable alternative?

Comment: Reading a textfile is sadly not an alternative

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunealy u cant , But you can understand what is the Char Set , and them you can "Cast" or "Convert" for UTF-8 , what id the stdout ?

Comment: The CodeSet is 1252 so basically, this means it is Windows-1252. How would you convert this value?