# Import txt files with UTF-8 special characters to xlsx

Tags: excel, vba, import, filesystemobject, txt

I have txt files that are automatically exported to me from another system (I cannot change this system). When I try to convert these txt files to excel with the following code (I created a subfolder xlsx manually):

```
Sub all()

   Dim sourcepath As String
   Dim sDir As String
   Dim newpath As String
    
    sourcepath = "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Test\"
    newpath = sourcepath & "xlsx\"
    
    'make sure subfolder xlsx was created before

    sDir = Dir$(sourcepath & "*.txt", vbNormal)
    Do Until Len(sDir) = 0
        Workbooks.Open (sourcepath & sDir)
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs Filename:=Replace(Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.FullName, ".")), sourcepath, newpath) & "xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close
        End With
        
        sDir = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```

it does work, however certain special characters, like ä,ö and Ü and so, are not properly displayed. I.e. when I open the xlsx files later on, I can see that these have been replaced by something like Ã¤ and so. I could use a work around and now start to replace these afterwards, however I would like to improve my txt to xlsx code. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524703/save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851473/read-utf-8-text-file-in-vbscript) it should be possible using ADODB.Stream. However, I don't know how to implement this into my code (loop) to get it working here in my case? If there is another approach instead of ADOB.Stream I am also fine with that. It is not necessary for me to use ADOB.Stream.

Comment: try `Workbooks.OpenText` with `Origin:=65001`. 65001 is the code page for UTF8.

Comment: Any reason for posting the same question twice? The solution proposed in the other question, should also work for this one, with the corresponding updates.

Comment: The reason is that indeed that this is the question about txt and not csv. That is why I separated these two questions. I currently have no solution for csv and that is why I wanted to try it with txt, as it seems to be the easier way, but I ran into the problem with special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried coercing the *code page*, using the `Origin` parameter? I don't know if you need a particular one, but the UTF-8 constant might be a starting point. I personally like this page as a reference source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers

So the solution might turn out to be as simple as this - it worked in my dummy tests:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const CP_UTF8 As Long = 65001

Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim sDir As String, sourcePath As String, fileName As String
    Dim fso As Object
    
    sourcePath = "C:\anyoldpath\"
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sDir = Dir(sourcePath & "*.txt", vbNormal)
    Do While Len(sDir) > 0
        fileName = sourcePath & "xlsx\" & fso.GetBaseName(sDir) & ".xlsx"
        Application.Workbooks.OpenText sourcePath & sDir, CP_UTF8
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        sDir = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to get your code working, to add the saving with the filename from my loop before. However, it does not work. Could you post a full working example? So it seems .FullName is not recognized anymore.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with your naming convention, but I'm pretty sure the `.FullName` property exists on the workbook object. I've amended the code to include a possible saving method but you'll need to adjust it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming that these `txt` files are tab delimited.*

The handling of the characters or `code page` it's managed by the `Origin` parameter of the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext) or by the [TextFilePlatform property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.textfileplatform) of the  `QueryTable` object.

These `txt` files should be opened with `Workbooks.OpenText` method, however in order to handle problem of the `Decimal.Separator` been different than then one in your system, I suggest to use the `QueryTable` method also applied to the tab separated files with a `csv` extension.

We just need to replace these lines:

```
sFile = Dir$(sPathSrc & "*.csv")
    sFilenameTrg = sPathTrg & Left(sFile, InStrRev(sFile, ".csv")) & "xlsx"
```

With these:

```
sFile = Dir$(sPathSrc & "*.txt")
    sFilenameTrg = sPathTrg & Left(sFile, InStrRev(sFile, ".txt")) & "xlsx"
```

No changes to Procedure `Open_Csv_As_Tab_Delimited_Then_Save_As_Xls, perhaps a change in the name to reflect its versatility.

Tested with this `tst` file:

[image]

Generated this `xlsx' file:

[image]

Hopefully, it should be straightforward to add these procedure to you project, let me know of any problem or question you might have with the resources used.

```
Sub Tab_Delimited_UTF8_Files_Save_As_Xlsx()
Dim sFilenameSrc As String, sFilenameTrg As String
Dim sPathSrc As String, sPathTrg As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim bShts As Byte, exCalc As XlCalculation

    sPathSrc = "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Test\"
    sPathTrg = sPathSrc & "xlsx\"

    Rem Excel Properties OFF
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        exCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .CalculateBeforeSave = False
        bShts = .SheetsInNewWorkbook
        .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    End With

    Rem Validate Target Folder
    If Len(Dir$(sPathTrg, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir sPathTrg

    Rem Process Csv Files
    sFile = Dir$(sPathSrc & "*.txt")
    Do Until Len(sFile) = 0
        
        sFilenameSrc = sPathSrc & sFile
        sFilenameTrg = sPathTrg & Left(sFile, InStrRev(sFile, ".txt")) & "xlsx"
        
        Call Open_Csv_As_Tab_Delimited_Then_Save_As_Xls(sFilenameSrc, sFilenameTrg)
        
        sFile = Dir$
    
    Loop

    Rem Excel Properties OFF
    With Application
        .SheetsInNewWorkbook = bShts
        .Calculation = exCalc
        .CalculateBeforeSave = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

…

```
Sub Open_Txt_As_Tab_Delimited_Then_Save_As_Xls(sFilenameSrc As String, sFilenameTrg As String)
Dim Wbk As Workbook
    
    Rem Workbook - Add
    Set Wbk = Workbooks.Add(Template:="Workbook")
    With Wbk
    
        Rem Txt File - Import
        With .Worksheets(1)
            
            Rem QueryTable - Add
            With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & sFilenameSrc, Destination:=.Cells(1))
                
                Rem QueryTable - Properties
                .SaveData = True
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
                .TextFileThousandsSeparator = ","
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
                .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                .TextFilePlatform = 65001       'Unicode (UTF-8)
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                
                Rem QueryTable - Delete
                .Delete
            
        End With: End With

        Rem Workbook - Save & Close
        .SaveAs Filename:=sFilenameTrg, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        .Close
    
    End With

    End Sub
```