# Edit Markdown file

Tags: excel, vba, markdown

We are trying to edit a markdown file in excel vba. Our idea is to add line(s) with the updates that we performed, those updates are listed on a spreadheet.
Up to now we wrote the following function

```
Public Sub UpdateChangeLog()
    Dim Output As String
    Dim FileSystemObject As FileSystemObject
    Set FileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Changelog = FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile(<Path to File>, ForReading)
    Output = Changelog.ReadAll
    .....
End Sub
```

Unluckily the Output is not readable

> "ÿþ#??A
> ??????A??????????????????????????A??A???A??????????????A??EEEE??A??A?????????????A

Same occurs if I try to read the file line by line. Do you know if what we are trying to achieve is feasible? If so, how can we do it?

Markdown File Content:

```
 # Changelog All notable changes to this component will be documented in this file.

 ## [Unreleased]
 
 ## [0.0.1] - dd-MMM-yyyy
 ### Initial Version
 - General schema only
 - Cloud agnostic
 - No cloud provider information available.
 
 # [Released]
 
 ## [1.0.0] - dd-MMM-yyyy
 General Description
```

Comment: Where/how are you viewing the output?  What is the encoding of the source file?

Comment: In addition to Tim's question, what is the input?

Comment: I view the same output adding a Watch and printing it on a cell. The encoding it UTF-8. Just add the input above

Comment: I think this Q&A may solve the issue: [Read utf-8 text file in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851473/read-utf-8-text-file-in-vbscript)