# Load and parse json file to find and replace the symbols in active document

Tags: json, vba, replace, ms-word

I have two `JSON` files, both have symbols and its replacements:

1. QCF_.json
2. QCF2.json

**You can find the JSON and Test files [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YCwzYDs1DXjyuhIlWvZc7m9x5y5r9hwi?usp=sharing).**

I need to find the specific symbol in the whole document and replace with its equivalent from either of json files. I am using precise replacement procedure, consist of two steps.

1. to `loop` through each `word` of `Active Document` and gather the relevant *font name* and *symbol*.
2. `Find/Replace` the symbols with font name.

The procedure is as follows:

```
Sub Find_Replace_Precise_Method()
    
    'Latest Improved
    
    Dim StartTime As Double, SecondsElapsed As Double
    Dim AD As Document
    Dim W As Range
    Dim Font, Sym, FN
    Dim QCFs
    
'   Load jSon Function
    If Load_jSon = False Then
        Application.StatusBar = "   There was an error while loading jSon!!!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
'   Time Calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    StartTime = Timer
    
    
'   Collection of fonts as well as symbols
    Set AD = ActiveDocument
    Set QCFs = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For Each W In AD.Words
        
    
        If QCFs.Exists(W.Font.Name & " " & Trim(W.Text)) = False And InStr(1, W.Font.Name, "QCF") > 0 Then
            
            'W.Select
            
            If Len(Trim(W.Text)) > 1 Then
                myF = W.Characters.First.Font.Name
                
                With W.Find
                    .Text = "(?)"
                    .Replacement.Text = "\1" & " "
                    .MatchWildcards = True
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                End With
                
                'On Error Resume Next
                    For Each C In W.Words
                        'If QCFs.Exists(myF & " " & Trim(C.Text)) = False Then
                            'C.Select
                            C.Font.Name = myF
                            QCFs(myF & " " & Trim(C.Text)) = x
                        'End If
                    Next
                'On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                
                'W.Select
                x = x + 1
                'QCFs.Add W.Font.Name & " " & Trim(W.Text), x
                QCFs(W.Font.Name & " " & Trim(W.Text)) = x
            
            
            End If
        
        End If
    Next

Application.StatusBar = x & " " & Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
x = 0

'   Find Replace
    For Each FontName In QCFs
        
            FN = Split(FontName)(0)
            Sym = Split(FontName)(1)
        
        If InStr(1, FontName, "QCF_") > 0 Then
            Font = Font_(FN)(Sym)
            
        Else
            Font = Font2(FN)(Sym)
            
        End If
        
        If Not Font = "" Then
            With AD.Range.Find
                .Font.Name = FN
                .Text = Sym
                .Replacement.Text = Font
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                        
            End With
        End If
        
        x = x + 1
        
    Next FontName
    

    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2) / 60
    MsgBox "Time Taken (min): " & vbTab & SecondsElapsed & vbCr & "Precise Replaces: " & vbTab & x, vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    
    
End Sub
```

To load `Json` to `Dictionary`, I am opening in word document, then parsing using [VBA-Parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases).  The function that loads JSON is as follows:

```
Function Load_jSon() As Boolean
    
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    
    If Not Font_ Is Nothing And Not Font2 Is Nothing Then
        Load_jSon = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    JJ = Split("QCF_.json QCF2.json")
    For Each j In JJ
        
        Application.StatusBar = "   Checking jSon ...   " & j
        
        jSONpath = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & j
        If Dir(jSONpath) = "" Then
            
            MsgBox j & " is NOT present in the same Folder, please! place the JSON file and then run again" _
            & vbCr & jSONpath, vbOKOnly + vbCritical
            
            Load_jSon = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    
    Next j
    
    
    For Each j In JJ
    
    '   Open JSON *********************************
        Application.StatusBar = "   Processing JSON ...   " & j
        Set oDoc = Documents.Open(ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & j, Visible:=False)
        With oDoc
            JsonText = .Range.Text
            .Close
        End With
        
        
    '   Parse JSON *********************************
        Application.StatusBar = "   Parsing JSON .....   " & j
        Set jSon = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)
            
        If Not jSon.Exists("fonts") Then
            
            MsgBox "Wrong JSON!!!" & vbCr & j, vbOKOnly + vbCritical
            Load_jSon = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        
        If j = "QCF_.json" Then
            Set Font_ = jSon("fonts")
        Else
            Set Font2 = jSon("fonts")
        End If
        
        Load_jSon = True

    Next j
    
End Function
```

Problem with the above function is that it takes a lot of time to open and load JSON.

**In Fact I used the following code to load JSON, it is fast in loading but replacing symbol is not matching.**

```
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream

Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile(ActiveDocument.Path & 
Application.PathSeparator & j, ForReading)
    JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
    JsonTS.Close
```

How can I optimize the complete process?

1. Opening JSON to read
2. find and replace symbols

Comment: It would be quite difficult to suggest improvements based only on the posted code, with no way to test changes (not having any sample json or doc files to test with).

Comment: @TimWilliams I am editing the question, add adding test file with json

Comment: If your JSON file has unicode: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-open-a-text-file-as-unicode/

Comment: @TimWilliams after loading the file in unicode using `Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile(ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & j, ForReading, False, -1)` I got 10001 parsing error "Expected {, ["

Comment: Sorry - should have tested that - use this instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/13855268/478884   Still takes a few seconds to parse the json though.

Comment: @TimWilliams works much better, in fact reduced time from 1~ min to 20~ seconds. what about the other part of subroutine and function, is there a room of correction?

Comment: Sorry I don't have much insight into the Word-related part.