# VBA: Writing Array Values to Respective Columns - Issue with Code Not Distributing Values Correctly

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have code for generating CSV files using VBA macro code. Everything is working fine except that it write all values/data in first column instead of respective columns where it actually belong.

Here is code:

```
Sub export_multiple_CSV()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = FindLastCell(shFile.Cells)
    Dim arr As New clsArray2D: arr.data = Range(shFile.Range("A1"), rg).value
    arr.RemoveRows 1
    Dim header As Variant: header = Range(shFile.Cells(1, 1), shFile.Cells(1, FindLastcolumn(shFile.Cells))).value
    
    Dim sRow As Long: sRow = 1
    Dim stopRow As Long: stopRow = arr.IndexOf("stop", 1)
    arr.data = arr.getRows(1, stopRow)
    
    Dim flag As Boolean: flag = False
    Dim counter As Long: counter = 1

    Dim i As Long, eRow As Long
    For i = 1 To stopRow
            eRow = arr.IndexOf("next", 1, sRow)
            If eRow = -1 Then
                    flag = True
                    eRow = stopRow
            End If
            
            'split the array from start to end row
            Dim temp As New clsArray2D
            temp.data = arr.getRows(sRow, eRow - sRow)
            'add header to ea
            'ch file
            temp.insertRows 1, header
            'update if adding columns to export correct file name
            Dim fName As String: fName = temp.value(2, 18)
            
            Dim ii As Long, jj As Long
            For ii = 1 To temp.rowCount
                    For jj = 1 To temp.columnCount
                            If IsError(temp.value(ii, jj)) Then temp.value(ii, jj) = Empty
                            
                            'option to replace semicolons and other delimiters, which is not a good solution
                            temp.value(ii, jj) = Replace(temp.value(ii, jj), ";", ",")
                            
                            If jj = 1 Then
                                    tempStr = temp.value(ii, jj)
                                    
                            Else
                                    tempStr = tempStr & ";" & temp.value(ii, jj)
                            End If
                    Next jj
                    temp.value(ii, 1) = tempStr
                    Call AppendLineToFile(tempStr, fName, ii)
            Next ii

            If flag = True Then Exit For
            
            'update starting row
            sRow = eRow + 1
            counter = counter + 1
    Next i

    'treure comentari per activar missatge d'exportació
    'MsgBox counter & " CSV generated!"
End Sub

Sub AppendLineToFile(textToAppend, fName As String, count As Long)
    Dim fs As Object: Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim filePath As String: filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fName & ".csv"
     If count = 1 Then
            If fs.FileExists(filePath) Then fs.DeleteFile filePath
    End If
    
    Dim fileStream As Object: Set fileStream = fs.OpenTextFile(filePath, 8, True, -1)
    
    fileStream.WriteLine textToAppend
    fileStream.Close
    
    ' Release the objects
    Set fileStream = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

It also exports unicode symbols.

The exported files should have utf8 encoding (which it already has) and data written in all columns where it belong.

Comment: What is `clsArray2D` ?  FYI you should quote any data which contains your separator `;`

Comment: I believe it's preferred to use ADODB.Stream to read/write UTF-8  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851473/read-utf-8-text-file-in-vbscript/13855268#13855268

Comment: *values/data in first column* How are you opening the csv ?

Comment: Please post some test data. Use [this](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to make a Markdown table