# vbscript serialize integer to byte array

Tags: arrays, vbscript, byte, binaryfiles

I want to write to a binary file the content of a vbscript variable that is a number. Is there any way to access the binary representation as a byte array? ( of integers, floats, etc). I have been trying to play with:
Adodb.recordset object, append a number field and then read it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_binarytostring/

Here is another thread discussing it too:

[Read and write binary file in VBscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060529/read-and-write-binary-file-in-vbscript)

```
intYourVar = 255
hexYourVar = HEX(intYourVar)
binYourVar = MultiByteToBinary(hexYourVar)

Function MultiByteToBinary(MultiByte)
  ' 2000 Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
  ' MultiByteToBinary converts multibyte string To real binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY)
  ' Using recordset
  Dim RS, LMultiByte, Binary
  Const adLongVarBinary = 205
  Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  LMultiByte = LenB(MultiByte)
  If LMultiByte>0 Then
    RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarBinary, LMultiByte
    RS.Open
    RS.AddNew
      RS("mBinary").AppendChunk MultiByte & ChrB(0)
    RS.Update
    Binary = RS("mBinary").GetChunk(LMultiByte)
  End If
  MultiByteToBinary = Binary
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. That actually works for strings but my number is written in ASCII. I was looking for a way to get, fir the number 255 for example, the 4 byte binary array: 0xFF000000

Comment: Ahh I see the dilemma now. I updated the code in the example.