# Create Shortcut to run with Powershell with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcut

I'm a bit lost. I want a powershell script that creates a shortcut linking to another powershell script. That shortcut should be able to run as administrator and the target should look like this. I made it manually like this and it works.

Target: `C:\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noexit "TARGETPATH\test.ps1"`

This is my code, but the arguments appear behind the target path instead in front of.

Is there also a possibility to replace the default logo to a specific one? i.e. the one of powershell

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
#Read current path
function Get-ScriptDirectory {
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}
$installpath = Get-ScriptDirectory

#create shortcut
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$installpath\EXE.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = """$installpath\test.ps1"""
$Shortcut.Arguments = "argumentA ArgumentB"
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "$installpath"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: Surely the `TargetPath` should be `C:\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe` and the arguments are `"-executionpolicy bypass -noexit ""$installPath\test.ps1"""` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Run As Administrator shortcut using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997799/how-to-create-a-run-as-administrator-shortcut-using-powershell)

Answer (score 3):

Icon and RunAs included

```
## Q:\Test\2018\04\27\SO_50057555.ps1
#Read current path
function Get-ScriptDirectory {
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}
$installpath = Get-ScriptDirectory
$RunScript= "Test.ps1"
$ShCutLnk = "PwSh $RunScript.lnk"

#create shortcut
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$installpath\$ShCutLnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$Shortcut.IconLocation = "C:\Windows\System32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe,0" # icon index 0
$Shortcut.Arguments = "-Nop -Executionpolicy bypass -NoExit ""$installPath\$RunScript"""
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "$installpath"
$Shortcut.Save()

## Make the Shortcut runas Administrator
## Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997799/how-to-create-a-run-as-administrator-shortcut-using-powershell
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$installpath\$ShCutLnk")
$bytes[0x15] = $bytes[0x15] -bor 0x20 #set byte 21 (0x15) bit 6 (0x20) ON
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$installpath\$ShCutLnk", $bytes)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks LotPings! I was having the same issue and your answer helps!