# What is the quickest way to get elevated rights in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-core, windows-terminal

It happens again and again that I am in a Powershell session and want to execute a command for which I need admin (elevated) rights.

My current workflow then:

```
1. pwd (ctrl+c)
2. open a new Powershell (run as administrator)
3. cd ctrl+v
```

This is very annoying and time-consuming, how can I optimise this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Run As Administrator shortcut using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997799/how-to-create-a-run-as-administrator-shortcut-using-powershell)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the standard way of creating a shortcut should do it:

- In a command box type *where wt.exe* to get the file path.
  This will most probably return `C:\Users\<yourname>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe`
- Open the path and right-click `wt.exe` (eventhough in there it shows 0 kb)
- Select 'Create Shortcut'
- Right-click the new shortcut and in the **General** tab change the name to `Windows Terminal (Admin)`
- In the **Shortcut** tab, click the Advanced button and check the box "Run as administrator"
- click OK
- Drag the shortcut to your desktop

Answer (score 0):

Theo's answer didn't work for me, but [this](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3145#issuecomment-628386646) one did. Copied:

1. Right click -> New -> Shortcut
   Type in `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start /b %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe` for the location
2. Give whatever name you want to give, finish.
3. List item
4. Right click on the newly created shortcut -> Properties -> Advanced -> Run as administrator