# How to send binary data with WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.Send method in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

How can I send binary data with the `send` method?
Apparently it treats the data as a string and it stops when it encounters a `NULL` character, which is legal in binary data. And ultimately not all the data get sent. If so, how can I set the size of the data to be sent then?

```
Set oHTTP = Createobject( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )
oHTTP.Open "PUT", myURL, False
oHTTP.Send binaryData
```

Suppose binaryData is read from a file for example, and it's size is `binaryDataSize` bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send files using the `ADODB.Stream` object and a proper content-type header:

```
Const adTypeBinary = 1

Set request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest")
Set dataStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

dataStream.Type = adTypeBinary
dataStream.Open
dataStream.LoadFromFile "C:\path\to\your.file"

request.Open "PUT", "http://your/url"
request.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"
request.Send dataStream
```

Comment: Thank's, I knew about ADODB but is it native to windows? or does it need some kind of installation?

Comment: No, that's native. (see MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/stream-object-ado?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately VBScript does not have proper routines for working with binary files. 
As a workaround you could use some approaches for reading binary files described here [Read and write binary file in VBscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060529/read-and-write-binary-file-in-vbscript)

If this still doesn't help then you could encode the data with base64 before sending [Base64 Encode String in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496751/base64-encode-string-in-vbscript)